# How to find out whether all inner ng-forms are valid or not?

Tags: angularjs

I have html code like this

```
<div class="section1">
    <div ng-repeat="item in Objs1">
        <ng-form name="myForm">
            <input require name="expression" ng-model="item.exp" />
            <label ng-show="myForm.expression.$error.required" class="error">*-required</label>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="--if any myForm is invalid--">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="section2">
    <input require name="first" ng-model="firstName" />
    <input require name="first" ng-model="SecondName" />
</div>
```

How can I know `--if any myForm is invalid--`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngForm can be nested. Just add an outer ngForm:

```
<ng-form name="parentForm">
<div ng-repeat="item in Objs">
    <ng-form name="myForm">
        <input require name="expression" ng-model="item.exp" />
        <label ng-show="myForm.expression.$error.required" class="error">*-required</label>
    </ng-form>
</div>
<button ng-disabled="parentForm.$invalid">Add</button>

</ng-form>
```

Comment: Its a huge form and it could be invalid at some other location so cannot use parentForm.$invalid

Comment: Dont be desperate and down vote the question. I have updated the question see now using ur solution the Add button will be disabled even the section1 is valid but section2 is invalid.

Comment: If you want to disable the button when any form is invalid, then that is what you asked for...